# Blazor Client->REST Service: how to pass log records?

Tags: blazor, .net-5

I have a NET 5 REST Service and Blazor client working with this service.
The REST service has a logging.

Users do not see the service console that's why I'd like to show the log records from the service on client app page.

How can I pass log records from the service to the client app?

Comment: Can you clarify? Why not just call your REST service to retrieve the logs.

Comment: The service has NLog  as a logger. It works now to console output. I cannot find how can I get log records and pass the List<string> to the client.